# Passing an argument to RecipientList defined in XML in Camel

Tags: xml, apache-camel

I have the following route defined in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<routes id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-3.0.1.xsd">

    <route>
        <from uri="activemq:queue?brokerURL=tcp://127.0.0.1:30001" />
        <bean beanType="com.mycompany.MyProcessor" />
        <setProperty name="brokerURL">
            <constant>tcp://127.0.0.1:30001</constant>
        </setProperty>
        <recipientList>
            <method method="getRecipients" beanType="com.mycompany.MyRecipientListProvider" />
        </recipientList>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Then I can consume *brokerURL* in *MyRecipientListProvider* class by using *@ExchangeProperty* injection. Is there any better way to pass an argument to RecipientList defined in XML?

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow

- If the information you want to pass is (or can be) **individual per message**, you can use **exchange properties or message headers**
- The difference between the two is that **exchange properties exist only during current route processing** since they are located in the exchange wrapper of the message. When the message is sent out (for example `.to(...)`), the properties are no more available
- **Message headers** on the other side (injectable with `@Headers`) are located inside the message and therefore whenever possible applied on outgoing messages and therefore **passed on as part of the message**.
- If the information is **static** (from the application point of view), so it stays the same value for all messages, you can use **standard application properties** injected by your application framework into the class where you need it.

Comment: The content is going to be static. I wonder if I can define such a property in a routing XML since I do not want to use java properties and I use bare Camel without any app framework.

Comment: I don't know about a possibility to define properties in a route XML, but if the value is static and you don't want to use an externalization like java properties, you can hardcode the value. You can do it as in your question or you can hardcode it inside `MyRecipientListProvider`. Because if the value changes, you have to redeploy anyway, no matter if it is hardcoded in route XML or anywhere else.

Comment: Basically, I want to configure MyRecipientListProvider. It can behave differently based on its configuration. Once applied it will be the same for each message.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
 public String[] getRecipients(@Simple("${exchangeProperty.brokerURL}") String brokerURL){
    //processing data
}
```